# How to return a list of strings that is a certain length?

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is create a program that returns a list of strings that are a certain length. I have a program made but I feel that it's extremely off

```
def lett(lst,n):
res = []
for a in range(1,len(lst)):
               if a == n
                   res = lst[a]
return res
```

what I want is to take the list and return all the words that are the length of n so if I were to do lett(["boo","hello","maybe","yes","nope"], ) it would return ['boo','yes']

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def lett(lst, n):
    return [x for x in lst if len(x) == n]
```

Or:

```
def lett(lst, n)
    return filter(lambda x: len(x) == n, lst)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is much simpler than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `filter` function

```
def lett(lst, n):
    return filter(lambda x: len(x) == n, lst)
```

This will return a list in Python 2. If you're using Python 3, it returns a `filter` object, so you might want to convert it to a list.

```
return list(filter(lambda x: len(x) == n, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def lett(lst, n):
    return [tmpStr for tmpStr in lst if len(tmpStr) == n]
```